# How to cross compile Haxe/OpenFL generated source code using minGW?

Tags: linux, g++, haxe, openfl, haxelib

I have got a CPP source files generated by **OpenFL/Haxe** for Linux (Fedora 21 x86_64).

I would like to attempt to cross-compile this to Windows executable using mingw-64 but does not know how to generate the proper **Makefile** for this as there where alot of cpp files in the scr folder.

How do I create this make file?

or

If there is an approach to configure **OpenFL/Haxe** to do cross compile using mingw-64 that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling Windows program from linux was not available from OpenFl during that time, I created several pull requests and code updates to enable it, however, the attempt was turned down. I think its due to manageability and market. But idea of coding in Linux for every OS makes Linux a powerful coding platform!

It took quite sometime to solve it on my end since some codes in its haxe component was needed to be updated. I continued my research and ended up contributing few codes to OpenFl and Haxe/Hxcpp.

New problems in compilation have arised that are far more difficult to solve, Ret-Mode have proposed a better solution that time. For those interested, check here: https://github.com/Ret-Mode/lime apply his fix to your Lime installation. The method for cross-compilation is as follows:

Installation on Linux for crosscompilation

1 Clone repository

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Ret-Mode/lime
```

2 Setup:

```
haxelib dev lime lime
```

2a Rebuild tools (from lime/${version}/tools folder):

```
haxe tools.hxml
```

3 First build for Your linux architecture:

```
haxelib run lime rebuild linux -DHXCPP_M32 -32
haxelib run lime rebuild linux -DHXCPP_M64 -64
```

3a Build lime for MinGW, also choose Your MinGW arch:

```
haxelib run lime rebuild windows -Dmingw -DHXCPP_M32 -32
haxelib run lime rebuild windows -Dmingw -DHXCPP_M64 -64
```

4 Build projects for Your arch:

```
haxelib run lime build windows -Dmingw -64
haxelib run lime build windows -Dmingw -32
```

5 If You have WINE installed, You should have Your app icon swapped. If not, app will have native icon, but will work